# Why does my selected/highlighted input text not trigger the input event all the time?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom-events, quasar-framework

I created a 4-pin field with the following behaviour: when one field is filled, the focus shifts to the next field (the cursor switches to the next input field). On deletion of a text value, the text in that input field is deleted and the cursor moves to the pin field before it.

The problem is that sometimes when a field with text is highlighted (e.g after a deletion), and another key is typed to overwrite the previous value (in the event of a mistake), the `input` event is not triggered, leaving the cursor still in that field (the cursor doesn't move to the next pin field). This will obviously not cause a great user experience and I would like to make it consistently switch pin fields when highlighted text is overwritten.

The relevant sections of code are posted below.

```js
data() {
  return {
    focusIndex: 1,
    inputOne: '',
    inputTwo: '',
    inputThree: '',
    inputFour: '',
    numberOfPinFields: 4,
  };
},

mounted() {
// this highlights the first pin field
  this.$refs[this.focusIndex].focus();
},

methods: {
  handlePinFieldDeletion() {
    if (this.focusIndex > 1) {
      this.focusIndex -= 1;
    }
  },
  
  handlePinFieldInput(value, maxNumberOfFields) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
     // after the focus index from the input field watch below is updated, increase the focusIndex value
       if (value.length === 1 && this.focusIndex < maxNumberOfFields) {
          this.focusIndex += 1;
        }
      });
    },
  ensurePinFieldHasOneInput(value) {
    return value.slice(0, 1);
  },
  highlightOnFocus(e, focusIndex) {
    // highlight the text
    e.target.select();
    // set the new focus index
    this.focusIndex = focusIndex;
  },
 }
 
 watch: {
  focusIndex(newValue) {
    this.$refs[newValue].focus();
  },
  inputOne(newValue) {
    // set focus index of first otp input field to 1 when it changes.
    // This will help with situations where the user doesn't use the input fields in numerical order
    this.focusIndex = 1;
    this.inputOne = this.ensurePinFieldHasOneInput(newValue);
  },

  inputTwo(newValue) {
  // set focus index of first otp input field to 2 when it changes.
  // This will help with situations where the user doesn't use the input fields in numerical order
    this.focusIndex = 2;
    this.inputTwo = this.ensurePinFieldHasOneInput(newValue);
  },

  inputThree(newValue) {
  // set focus index of first otp input field to 3 when it changes.
  // This will help with situations where the user doesn't use the input fields in numerical order
    this.focusIndex = 3;
    this.inputThree = this.ensurePinFieldHasOneInput(newValue);
  },
  inputFour(newValue) {
    // set focus index of first otp input field to 4 when it changes.
    // This will help with situations where the user doesn't use the input fields in numerical order
    this.focusIndex = 4;
    this.inputFour = this.ensurePinFieldHasOneInput(newValue);
  },
  },
```

```html
<form>
  ...
  <q-input
    type="password"
    input-class="text-center"
    maxlength="1"
    @keyup.delete="handlePinFieldDeletion"
    @input="handlePinFieldInput($event, numberOfPinFields)"
    v-number-only
    @focus="highlightOnFocus($event, 1)"
    borderless
    ref="1"
    v-model="inputOne"
  />
  <q-input
        type="password"
        input-class="text-center"
        maxlength="1"
        v-number-only
        @focus="highlightOnFocus($event, 2)"
        @keyup.delete="handlePinFieldDeletion"
        @input="handlePinFieldInput($event, numberOfPinFields)"
        borderless
        ref="2"
        v-model="inputTwo"
      />
      <q-input
        type="password"
        input-class="text-center"
        maxlength="1"
        v-number-only
        @focus="highlightOnFocus($event, 3)"
        @keyup.delete="handlePinFieldDeletion"
        @input="handlePinFieldInput($event, numberOfPinFields)"
        borderless
        ref="3"
        v-model="inputThree"
      />
      <q-input
        type="password"
        input-class="text-center"
        v-number-only
        @focus="highlightOnFocus($event, 4)"
        maxlength="1"
        @keyup.delete="handlePinFieldDeletion"
        @input="handlePinFieldInput($event, numberOfPinFields)"
        borderless
        ref="4"
        v-model="inputFour"
      />
  ...
</form>
```

Comment: I found the code missing numberOfPinFields!

Comment: Hi, @Abuabdellah. I forgot to include it, but I have updated the code.

Comment: peace be upon those who follow guidance, @Tony. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests and I see the error in the **watch** when the overwrite with the same value i.e field 1 had 5 highlighted and updated by 5 again.

Code:

```
 watch: {
  focusIndex(newValue) {
    this.$refs[newValue].focus();
  },
  inputOne(newValue) {
    this.$q.notify({
        message: 'inputOne changed',
        caption: 'moments ago',
        color: 'secondary'
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have figured it out, though and I posted my solution.

Comment: I found your solution similar to what I mentioned about the reason. anyway seems fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The `maxLength` attribute would not allow for an `input` event to be triggered when the maximum number of values are contained in the input field.

However, what caused the pin field to work sometimes after the highlighted value is overwritten, and not to work other times, is that when the user inputs the same value as what was previously there (i.e the overwritten value is the same as the previous value), the `input` event will not be triggered, while once a different value is used to overwrite the previous value, the `input` event is triggered.

I discovered this via trial and error. I can only assume that this is the default browser behaviour, as I couldn't confirm it anywhere else.

To fix this issue, I removed the `maxLength` attribute and I refactored the code, and viola!, it works. The refactored code is shown below.

```js
<script>
const generatePinInputs = (numberOfPinFields) => {
  const objectOfPinFields = {};
  // create an array of values of the number of pin fields
  Array(numberOfPinFields).fill('').forEach((field, index) => {
    objectOfPinFields[index + 1] = field;
  });
  return objectOfPinFields;
};
export default {
  name: 'app-pin',
  props: {
    numberOfPinFields: {
      type: Number,
      default: 4,
    },

  },
  mounted() {
    // switched from quasar's q-input to input because of error thrown about v-model mutating prop value
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      // After all asynchronous actions (including dialog popup showing pin fields), focus on the first input
      this.$refs[1][0].focus();
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pinInputs: generatePinInputs(this.numberOfPinFields),
    };
  },

  computed: {
    pinFilled() {
      return Object.values(this.pinInputs).join('');
    },
  },

  watch: {
    pinFilled(newValue) {
      // if all 4 pin fields have been completed, emit completed
      if (newValue.length === this.numberOfPinFields) {
        this.$emit('completed', newValue);
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleInput(e, index) {
      const { value } = e.target;
      // if there is no value, do nothing - the deletion of a value also calls the input value
      // this prevents an error when a value is deleted
      if (!value) {
        return;
      }
      // replace the data property with the latest value that is typed
      this.pinInputs[index] = value.slice(-1);
      // sometimes this is required by vue to override default browser behaviour
      this.$refs[index][0].value = value.slice(-1);
      if (index !== this.numberOfPinFields) {
        this.$refs[index + 1][0].focus();
      }
    },
    handleDelete(index) {
      if (index !== 1) {
        this.$refs[index - 1][0].focus();
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <transition appear enter-active-class="animated slideInRight">
    <form class="appPin">
      <input
        v-for="(index) in numberOfPinFields"
        :key="index"
        input-class="text-center"
        @input="handleInput($event, index)"
        @keyup.delete="handleDelete(index)"
        v-number-only
        type="password"
        inputmode="numeric"
        :ref="index"
        v-model="pinInputs[index]"
      />
    </form>
  </transition>
</template>
```